# Why this list mutation behavior in python method call?

Tags: python, list, methods

I am creating multiple urls to create a thread pool for parallel pagination calls. When the method is directly called I get proper results. when this method is imported from another modules ,results are weird.

method to create urls

```
total_pages = 44
params = {'paginateBy': {'size': 100, 'pageNumber': 1},
 'sort': {}}

def create_urls(params,totalPages):
    url_list = []
    for i in range(1,totalPages):
        params['paginateBy']['pageNumber'] = i
        url_list.append(params)
    return url_list
url_list = create_urls(params,totalPages)
```

output when called directly

```
['{"paginateBy": {"size": 100, "pageNumber": 1}, "sort": {}}',
 '{"paginateBy": {"size": 100, "pageNumber": 2}, "sort": {}, }',
 '{"paginateBy": {"size": 100, "pageNumber": 3}, "sort": {}, }',
 ,..........

output when imported from other module

['{"paginateBy": {"size": 100, "pageNumber": 44}, "sort": {}, }',
 '{"paginateBy": {"size": 100, "pageNumber":44}, "sort": {}, }',44
 '{"paginateBy": {"size": 100, "pageNumber": 44}, "sort": {}, }',
 '{"paginateBy": {"size": 100, "pageNumber":44}, "sort": {}, .....
```

Comment: I doubt that it works for direct call. You are modifying the same dictionary again and again and append a new reference to it to url_list

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work for, as you are making the same change for the same key-value pair.

To make it work :

```
def create_urls(params,totalPages):
    url_list = []
    for i in range(1,totalPages):
        params = {'paginateBy': {'size': 100, 'pageNumber': i},'sort': {}}
        url_list.append(params)
    return url_list
```

I hope this will help.